# Function doesn't run when I click on the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

So I have a simple JQuery code:

```
$(function () {
  var podatoci;
  var i;

  $(".front").on("load", init());
  $("#remove").on("click", toggleRemove());

  function init() {
    load();
  }

  function load() {
    $.get("data.json", function (data, status) {
      podatoci = data;
      fill();
    })
  }

  function toggleRemove() {
    console.log("Yes");
    $(".likse-dislikes").toggle();
  }

  function fill() {
    for (i = 0; i < podatoci.length; i++) {
      $("#container").append("<div class='wrap'><img class='img' src='"+podatoci[i].url+"'/><div class='likes-dislikes'><img class='like' src='sources/like.png'/><img class='dislike' src='sources/dislike.png'/></div></div>");
    }
  }
});
```

When I click on the button with ID: `remove` it runs the `toggleRemove()` function.

However when I run the web page and when I got to to the console when I click on the button the function doesn't run, instead it does `Console.log("OK")` only once presumably when the page is loaded. Can anyone please explain where is the problem and how do I fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the page have an element with `id="remove"`?  Where's your HTML?

Comment: There is no  `#remove` element. If there is and you're dynamically appending it to the DOM, you need to use a delegated event handler. You also need to give the *function reference* to the event handlers, not the *function response*. Change to `.on('load', init)` and `.on('click', toggleRemove);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
$("#remove").on("click", toggleRemove());
```

This executes `toggleRemove` *once*, when the page loads, and sets the handler to the *result* of that function.  (Which is `undefined` because the function doesn't return anything.)

You want to set the handler to the function *itself*, not the result of the function:

```
$("#remove").on("click", toggleRemove);
```

Additionally, if your element is being added to the page *after* this code executes (we don't know, though the code shown implies some dynamic elements being added) then you'd need to delegate the event:

```
$(document).on("click", "#remove", toggleRemove);
```

Answer (score 0):

You spelled the class name incorrectly on your remove function.

$(".**likse**-dislikes").toggle();

Change it to

```
$(".likes-dislikes").toggle();
```

Comment: How do you know the spelling mistake is not made in the html as well?

Comment: Because on his fill() function, he's appending elements with the .likes-dislikes class

Comment: Oh yea, I see it now but this typo would not of caused the issue the OP is describing. If this was the issue then the console log would of triggered each time the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

As I can see here `$(".front").on("load", init());` `$("#remove").on("click", toggleRemove());` you call your call back in time when you register event listener. Try this: `$(".front").on("load", init);` `$("#remove").on("click", toggleRemove);`

Answer (score -3):

You could use `$scope.apply(handler)`

```
$scope.apply(function () {
    // Angular is now aware that something might of changed
    $scope.changeThisForMe = true;
});
```

Comment: OP has made no mention of using angular

Comment: This question is tagged with jquery and no angular

Comment: True that, my bad.